# Android Input View (Dialog?)

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to show an input dialog exactly like this:
[image]

On the android dev page I couldn't find a fitting dialog type? (Alerts, simple dialogs and confirmation dialogs)
I would appreciate it if someone could explain which component this is.

Comment: You can use a alert dialog with custom layout .

Answer (score 0):

You should use simple Dialog  fragment.

Refer following link http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-dialog-fragment-example